# Closing a file in java, using functional programming

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm new and I have a question.
How can I close a file in java using functional programming(using lambda)?

How can I convert for example file.close() into something that looks in a functional manner?

Comment: What's wrong with file.close()?

Comment: try to read this http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/03/25/java8-examples-string-number-math-files/ the second paragraph before last paragraph.

Comment: @xs0 i need a functional manner for the faculty,i already use the function close()

Comment: if the duplicate I've suggested doesn't answer your question then keep following the duplicates of each post and eventually you'll find what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "functional manner"? Maybe with some example of the same code in "non-functional manner" and then also in "functional manner", so that we can understand the difference.. (the way I understand functional, your original question makes no sense)

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to clean the 'close a resource' is try with resources (But thats not functional..):

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile")){

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thanks mate. But I already use this